# Quiero saber como puedo hacer un salto de linea en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

-- Quiero que en mi resultado de mi select me figure el salto de linea, todo esto lo hago para poder llamarlo en un procedure que tengo y haga la acción de enviar a un archivo plano.

```
DECLARE @CargasFinalizadas AS TABLE(

    In_Id_Carga Bigint,
    Ch_Ruc Char(16)

)
--poblar datos
INSERT INTO @CargasFinalizadas (In_Id_Carga,Ch_Ruc) VALUES(1,'123' )
INSERT INTO @CargasFinalizadas (In_Id_Carga,Ch_Ruc) VALUES (2,'124')
INSERT INTO @CargasFinalizadas  (In_Id_Carga,Ch_Ruc) VALUES (3,'125')
--declarar variables
declare @Texto nVARCHAR(max) = ''
declare @Texto1 int
declare @Texto2 varchar(16)
--Consulta
    DECLARE Cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT In_Id_Carga , Ch_Ruc FROM @CargasFinalizadas
OPEN Cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1 INTO @Texto1 ,@Texto2
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @Texto = @Texto + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + convert(varchar, @Texto1) + ',' + @Texto2
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1 INTO @Texto1 ,@Texto2
END
Close Cursor1
Deallocate Cursor1
Select @Texto
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya estás haciendo el salto de línea. Pero los saltos de linea son ignorados cuando muestras los resultados en el grid. Prueba con salida a texto.

Comment: Cuando  pongo mi variable en mi store procedure que su funcion es que me imprima en un archivo plano me sale como en la imagen, yo quisiera que se ponga en un salto de linea como podria hacerlo entonces

Comment: Entonces el problema es en tu STORED procedure. Los saltos de línea ahí están. Prueba cambiando `SELECT @Texto` por `PRINT @Texto` para que lo compruebes.

Comment: Ahora que usar un cursor para concatenar texto, es muy ineficiente. Se puede hacer todo en un simple SELECT.

Comment: O no hay otra alternativa de guardar resultados multiples en una variable ?

Comment: Si tambien el cursor esta de más creo en mi solucion